# Not able to get results in Solr

Tags: solr

I do a full-import and I get the following response for the below command
http://localhost:8983/solr/karan/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true&clean=false

But when I run the following snippet
public class SolrJSearcher {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
       SolrClient  solr = new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/karan");
     SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.set("q", "karan");
     QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
     SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
     for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
       System.out.println(results.get(i));
     }
   }
 }
```

I get no results even though two rows are there.If I change the q to *:* I get two results without the name karan.Can you please clarify what is going wrong in this If I try in the sample project techproducts with the same changes I get the results as expected.
Solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
     </lst>
        </requestHandler>
```

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/greed" 
              user="root" 
              password="kalkoti"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" 
            query="select id,name from testing">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have created the collection karan using
solr create -c karan

Response from full-import

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">12</int>
</lst>
<lst name="initArgs">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<str name="command">full-import</str>
<str name="status">idle</str>
<str name="importResponse"/>
<lst name="statusMessages">
<str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">1</str>
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">2</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">2</str>
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2015-07-06 13:55:26</str>
<str name="">
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 2 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
</str>
<str name="Committed">2015-07-06 13:55:26</str>
<str name="Time taken">0:0:0.431</str>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: If your error is with a project you have created, and not the sample project, how can people help you debug the issue? People need to be able to recreate the issue before they can help you debug it.

Comment: What do u want me to post?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact query you've sent via SolrJ and it might also be helpful to know if you get the expected results if you run the query on the admin panel. You should also add the relevant part of your schema.xml and data-config.xml.

Comment: Just to check, you do realise that others won't be able to access your localhost URL, right?

Comment: I am running it locally.

Comment: @TMBT copied the schem.xml from techproducts as it is as it contains id,name.

Comment: Is "karan" in the name field of your schema? Out of curiosity, what happens if you do query.set("q", "name:karan*");? How about just query.set("q", "karan*");?

Comment: For "name:karan*) I get the response as Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/karan: undefined field name. For ("q","karan*") I get no results.karan is not present in the schema it is a database record.

Comment: What ids and names come back from Solr if you search using : as your q?

Comment: *:* returns SolrDocument{id=1, _version_=1505955953197973504}
SolrDocument{id=2, _version_=1505955953200070656} which is what I want with the names.But the names are not found.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying what fields should be written to in your data-config.xml file. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

You haven't given us your full schema.xml or solrconfig.xml files, so it is hard to tell you exactly what to do, but Solr uses the *select* request handler as default, which uses the **text** field as the default search field. Meaning you will need to map whatever database column contains the term karan to the text field.